Most efficient way to create a set of n integers
I am trying to create a set of n integers: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n}.
What is the most efficient way to do so?
It looks like {for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) i}} is more efficient than List.generate(n, (j) => j).toSet():
On the dartpad:
void main() {
  const size = 1000;
  const n = 1000;
  final startList = DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    final s = List.generate(n, (j) => j).toSet();
  }
  final endList = DateTime.now();
  print('List: ${endList.difference(startList)}');

  final startSet = DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    final s = {for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) i};
  }
  final endSet = DateTime.now();
  print('Set: ${endSet.difference(startSet)}');
}

List: 0:00:00.194000
Set: 0:00:00.104000

But are there other (more efficient) ways?

Can you represent them instead as boolean functions? final s = (int v) => v >= 0 && v < n;

I suppose you suggest then to use s(myInt) instead of s.contains(myInt)? That would be a good idea. Unfortunately, in my case, Set s can be modified later on by adding or removing some ints. I need a Set here and I'm trying to have some initial values in it

I'd ignore small differences in performance and use the literal {for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) i} because it's readable and direct. I would avoid anything that creates another object, whether list or iterable, before creating the set. Since there is no Set.generate, that really only leaves the literal, and doing var set = <int>{}; for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) set.add(i);, and the literal should be at least as efficient as that. (If not, it can be optimized in the future, which more convoluted approaches are less likely to.)

Be aware when discussing "performance" that different compilation targets have different performance characteristics. Compiling to the web, as JS or Wasm, or compiling natively for x64 or ARM32, or running as JIT on either of those, can all behave differently.
You can try to optimize for one platform, but I (again) recommend just writing the most direct code possible, and assume that every compiler does it best for that thing (and if it doesn't, that it eventually will).

I can't suggest a more efficient method of creating a set of integers but thought of adding more detailed benchmark scores:
// ignore_for_file: unused_local_variable
import 'package:benchmark_runner/benchmark_runner.dart';

const n = 100000;

final list = List.generate(n, (j) => j);

void main(List<String> args) {
  benchmark('create set', () {
    final set = {for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) i};
  });
  benchmark('create list, list -> set', () {
    final set = List.generate(n, (j) => j).toSet();
  });
  benchmark('create iterable, iterable -> set', () {
    final set = Iterable.generate(n).toSet();
  });
  benchmark('list -> set', () {
    final set = list.toSet();
  });
  benchmark('create list', () {
    final list = List.generate(n, (j) => j);
  });
}

The benchmark scores for a set size of n = 1000 are listed below:
$ dart benchmark/set_benchmark.dart 
[273ms:410us] create set
  mean: 32.21 ± 1.58 us, median: 31.89 ± 1.52 us
  ▉▉▆______ sample size: 29 (averaged over 64 runs)

[270ms:161us] create list, list -> set
  mean: 41.075 ± 6.62 us, median: 40.13 ± 5.80 us
  ▇▉▄▁_____ sample size: 28 (averaged over 54 runs)

[271ms:799us] create iterable, iterable -> set
  mean: 39.17 ± 9.42 us, median: 35.89 ± 1.047 us
  ▉▂▄______  55  _____ sample size: 29 (averaged over 57 runs)

[268ms:379us] list -> set
  mean: 35.88 ± 7.35 us, median: 33.31 ± 0.69 us
  ▉▇▂_______  51  _____ sample size: 29 (averaged over 60 runs)

[236ms:317us] create list
  mean: 1.80 ± 0.10 us, median: 1.81 ± 0.086 us
  ▂▁▁▇▅▉▂▁▁_________ sample size: 86 (averaged over 221 runs)

Benchmark scores for a set size of n = 100000:
$ dart benchmark/set_benchmark.dart 
[783ms:310us] create set
  mean: 9.84 ± 1.67 ms, median: 9.53 ± 0.37 ms
  _____▄▉▁▂________  30  _____ sample size: 53

[888ms:104us] create list, list -> set
  mean: 12.0018 ± 0.60 ms, median: 11.87 ± 0.46 ms
  ▃▉▉▃▂___▁____ sample size: 49

[818ms:249us] create iterable, iterable -> set
  mean: 10.48 ± 0.40 ms, median: 10.40 ± 0.42 ms
  ▂▅▉▅▂▁___ sample size: 50

[812ms:429us] list -> set
  mean: 10.45 ± 0.72 ms, median: 10.15 ± 0.43 ms
  __▆▉▄▁__▁_▁_▁_ sample size: 51

[322ms:644us] create list
  mean: 1.91 ± 0.71 ms, median: 1.51 ± 0.51 ms
  ▉▄___▁▁__ sample size: 59

The benchmark scores show that, in this case, generating a set using a collection-for is marginally faster than generating a list and converting the list to a set.

I agree with the conclusion. Another approach that is very close to the literal is var set = <int>{}; for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) set.add(i); (unsurpricingly, since that's what the literal does behind the scenes). The literal-for is just more readable.
Creating a set is inherently more expensive than creating a list because it has to check for hash collision on each addition.
